# Subset a dataframe based on reciprocity conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have the following data frame structure

| date | latitude |
| --- | --- |
| 1951-03-22 | 66.08106 |
| 1951-03-22 | 59.59117 |
| 1951-04-08 | 59.59117 |
| 1952-10-20 | 55.41972 |
| 1960-08-12 | 66.05653 |
| 1960-09-10 | 66.08106 |

What I would like to do is: select the rows for all unique latitude and if there are 2 (or more) exact same latitudes, I want to keep only the one that has the earliest date **but for each year**.

So, for my previous example, it would give the following subset, without only the 3rd row:

| date | latitude |
| --- | --- |
| 1951-03-22 | 66.08106 |
| 1951-03-22 | 59.59117 |
| 1952-10-20 | 55.41972 |
| 1960-08-12 | 66.05653 |
| 1960-09-10 | 66.08106 |

Many thanks for the help.

PS: maybe it is important to precise that class(df$date) is "Date" and class(df$latitude) is "numeric".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouped by 'latitude' and `year` extracted from 'date', use `slice_max` to extract the row with max date, and then remove the 'year' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%    
    # grouped by latitude, and year extracted from Date class 
    # year is from lubridate
    group_by(latitude, year = year(date)) %>% 
    # slice 1 row from each group, ordered by the 'date' column
    slice_max(n = 1, order_by = date) %>%
    # remove the grouping
    ungroup %>%
    # remove the year column
    select(-year) %>%
    arrange(date)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  date       latitude
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 1951-03-22     66.1
2 1951-04-08     59.6
3 1952-10-20     55.4
4 1960-08-12     66.1
5 1960-09-10     66.1
```

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks a lot. I can't accept your answer before 5 minutes :) any chance that you explain what every line does precisely?

Comment: You have erased the  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% line?

Comment: @Recology when I noticed that your post shows `maybe it is important to precise that class(df$date) is "Date"`.  We don't need to do a computation twice

Comment: I have a follow-up on my question, because if the code works well for grouping by latitude, when I map the results, it keeps making the difference by longitude, is there a way to avoid that? Saying it in an other way, I would like to keep the earliest data per year that has the same latitude **regardless** of their longitude.

Comment: I found a practical solution which is to replace all the longitude values by the same one, but if you have more elegant I would like to know it, thank you in advance